# java program to find out wrong column on comparing 2 files

Tags: java

I try to insert like

```
INSERT INTO T1 (column1, column2, column3, column4) VALUES (value1, value2, value3);
```

The above insert statement is present in the form of a script as a txt file.

where 'column4' is not a column that is existing in the table. 
I have complied xls file list of tables agaist columns

```
xls file
T1 ---- column1
T1 ---- column2
T1 ---- column3

T2 ---- column1
T2 ---- column2
T2 ---- column3
T2 ---- column4
```

Upon comparing the txt file which has script and xls file list, it has to jot out column4 as an extra column.

Can someone help me with this ?
Thanks

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. MySQL, SQL Server, etc..) that you are using

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the query sintax, I guess you are trying to insert data into Oracle Database from a JAVA program.

What you can do is to write your code using try and catch.

```
try{

     String query = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (column1, column2, column3, column4) VALUES (value1, value2, value3);"
     Statement stm = connection.createStatement();
     stm.execute(query);

}
catch(SQLException ex){

     System.out.println(ex.getErrorCode());
     System.out.println(ex.getErrorMessage());

}
```

I believe that by analizing the string in ex.getErrorMessage you will be able to conclude which column is incorrectly identified. 
It will look something like this: ORA-00904: "column4": invalid identifier

And by using substring functions and similar, you could see where the problem is
More info on SQL Exception: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/SQLException.html

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use DatabaseMetaData: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html, which allows you to list the fields of a table. Some code available here: https://dzone.com/articles/listing-schematablecolumn

but "validating" a query is by far not a trivial task (your query may have other problems instead of only a naming of a column, and this is DB-dependant)

Comment: As we insert a lot of data, it is basically a config management project where many a times column names are excess. Just for this I thought I can find something which mentions out that column name that is in excess

Comment: What I wanted to warn is if you are using this in production code, this will be very difficult to handle all cases. But for an helper, used sporadically, this can do the job. DatabaseMetaData helps to find out how many fields and what type has a table. Use it where you need it to validate your queries, but don't spread it in production code.

Comment: I just understood the actual logic. It is even before sending the production as it to avoid additional column being added in the script from testing env.